# Commenting out a set of lines in a shell script

Tags: unix, shell, comments, editing

I was wondering if there is a way to comment out a set of lines in a shell script.
How could I do that? We can use /* */ in other programming languages.
This is most useful when I am converting/using/modifying another script 
and I want to keep the original lines instead of deleting.

It seems a cumbersome job to find and prefix # for all the lines which are not used.

Lets say there are 100 lines in the script in consequent lines which are not to used.
I want to comment them all out in one go. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block Comments in a Shell Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947897/block-comments-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
if false
then

...code...

fi
```

`false` always returns false so this will always skip the code.

Comment: bash is not a pre-processed language... this trick is useful when used in C as a preprocessor command.  If you do it as you suggested you can't avoid possible syntax errors.

Comment: I actually don't mind being informed of syntax errors in code that is "disabled".

Comment: :/ This is certainly not the best answer, IMO.

Comment: The best answer is below, by @asev69

Comment: @Artelius Sometimes, you want to comment *because* there are unsolved syntax errors that you're not bothered about at the moment

Answer (score 49):

The most versatile and safe method is putting the comment into a void quoted
`here-document`, like this:

```
<<"COMMENT"
    This long comment text includes ${parameter:=expansion}
    `command substitution` and $((arithmetic++ + --expansion)).
COMMENT
```

Quoting the `COMMENT` delimiter above is necessary to prevent parameter
expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion, which would happen
otherwise, as Bash manual [states](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) and POSIX shell standard [specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04).

In the case above, not quoting `COMMENT` would result in variable `parameter`
being assigned text `expansion`, if it was empty or unset, executing command
`command substitution`, incrementing variable `arithmetic` and decrementing
variable `expansion`.

Comparing other solutions to this:

Using `if false; then comment text fi` requires the comment text to be
syntactically correct Bash code whereas natural comments are often not, if
only for possible unbalanced apostrophes. The same goes for `: || { comment text }`
construct.

Putting comments into a single-quoted void command argument, as in `:'comment
text'`, has the drawback of inability to include apostrophes. Double-quoted
arguments, as in `:"comment text"`, are still subject to parameter expansion,
command substitution and arithmetic expansion, the same as unquoted
here-document contents and can lead to the side-effects described above.

Using scripts and editor facilities to automatically prefix each line in a
block with '#' has some merit, but doesn't exactly answer the question.

Answer (score 27):

You can also put multi-line comments using:

```
: '
comment1comment1
comment2comment2
comment3comment3
comment4comment4
'
```

As per the Bash Reference for [Bourne Shell builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)

> : (a colon)
>
> : [arguments]
>
> Do nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections. The return status is zero.

Thanks to Ikram for pointing this out in the post [Shell script put multiple line comment](http://cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-comment-out-multiple-line-code)

Comment: It is also important to note that there is a space between the colon and the single apostrophe. Even though the author has made it clear, some like yours truly might miss it and it will not run without the space.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. It is very clear and concise.

Comment: You can open and close your comment with `: ' :`. :)

Comment: This won't work and would be dangerous if the commented code contains single quotes. e.g. `: 'echo foo'<(echo bar >&2)'baz'`.

Comment: @spbnick
You can use a different delimiter, for example : " (double quote) if your commended code has single-quote marks in it.  I don't know for sure if other characters can be used as delimiters, but it makes sense that they would work.

Answer (score 21):

You can use a 'here' document with no command to send it to.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Say Something"
<<COMMENT1
    your comment 1
    comment 2
    blah
COMMENT1
echo "Do something else"
```

[Wikipedia Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Comment: The contents of an unquoted here-document is still subject to parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion and thus to possible side-effects, like executing text in backticks as commands.

Answer (score 10):

Text editors have an amazing feature called search and replace. You don't say what editor you use, but since shell scripts tend to be *nix, and I use VI, here's the command to comment lines 20 to 50 of some shell script:

```
:20,50s/^/#/
```

Comment: That's how I would do it. To uncomment, try this: :20,50s/^#//

Answer (score 5):

```
: || {
your code here
your code here
your code here
your code here
}
```

Comment: This is no better than `if false; then … fi`, because it does not hide the [possibly ill-formed] code from syntax analysis.

Answer (score 2):

What if you just wrap your code into function?

So this:

```
cd ~/documents
mkdir test
echo "useless script" > about.txt
```

Becomes this:

```
CommentedOutBlock() {
  cd ~/documents
  mkdir test
  echo "useless script" > about.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this [site](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-comment-out-multiple-line-code/):

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=bar
: '
This is a test comment
Author foo bar
Released under GNU 
'

echo "Init..."
# rest of script
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the editor that you're using there are some shortcuts to comment a block of lines.

Another workaround would be to put your code in an "if (0)" conditional block ;)

Comment: 0 is truthy in bash, though. if I'm not mistaken, `if (0); then` will always execute

Answer (score -1):

This Perl one-liner comments out lines 1 to 3 of the file `orig.sh` inclusive (where the first line is numbered 0), and writes the commented version to `cmt.sh`.

```
perl -n -e '$s=1;$e=3; $_="#$_" if $i>=$s&&$i<=$e;print;$i++' orig.sh > cmt.sh
```

Obviously you can change the boundary numbers as required.

If you want to edit the file in place, it's even shorter:

```
perl -in -e '$s=1;$e=3; $_="#$_" if $i>=$s&&$i<=$e;print;$i++' orig.sh
```

#### Demo

```
$ cat orig.sh 
a
b
c
d
e
f

$ perl -n -e '$s=1;$e=3; $_="#$_" if $i>=$s&&$i<=$e;print;$i++' orig.sh > cmt.sh

$ cat cmt.sh 
a
#b
#c
#d
e
f
```

Comment: sed is simpler: `echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6" | sed -e "2,4 s/^/#/"`