# How to comment out particular lines in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Can anyone suggest how to comment particular lines in the shell script other than `#`?

Suppose I want to comment five lines.  Instead of adding `#` to each line, is there any other way to comment the five lines?

Comment: Unfortunately not in sh, Bash, and Perl.

Comment: No. Comments can just be done with leading `#`. There is no multiple lines comments (such as `/* ... */` in php).

Comment: They're called "block comments" by the way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block Comments in a Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947897/block-comments-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 38):

You can comment section of a script using a conditional.

For example, the following script:

```
DEBUG=false
if ${DEBUG}; then
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
echo 5
fi
echo 6
echo 7
```

would output:

```
6
7
```

In order to *uncomment* the section of the code, you simply need to comment the variable:

```
#DEBUG=false
```

(Doing so would print the numbers 1 through 7.)

Answer (score 27):

Yes (although it's a *nasty* hack). You can use a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) thus:

```
#!/bin/sh

# do valuable stuff here
touch /tmp/a

# now comment out all the stuff below up to the EOF
echo <<EOF
...
...
...
EOF
```

What's this doing ? A `heredoc` feeds all the following input up to the terminator (in this case, EOF) into the nominated command. So you can surround the code you wish to comment out with

```
echo <<EOF
...
EOF
```

and it'll take all the code contained between the two EOFs and feed them to `echo` (`echo` doesn't read from stdin so it all gets thrown away).

Note that with the above you can put anything in the `heredoc`. It doesn't have to be valid shell code (i.e. it doesn't have to parse properly).

This is very nasty, and I offer it only as a point of interest. You can't do the equivalent of C's `/* ... */`

Comment: You probably want to use something other than `echo`, or else send the echo to /dev/null.

Comment: Yes. The command doesn't matter. I do note that on my Cygwin terminal, however, that echo doesn't read stdin. I suspect implementations differ

Comment: No, it doesn't *read* anything, but it does *output* a blank line. `true` might be better.

Comment: Or `:`, which may be more efficient than `true` (although really, neither is going to slow your script down). For the purposes of commenting code, it might be more readable, for the very reason that it doesn't *look* like it's supposed to be doing anything.

Answer (score 9):

for single line comment add   **#**   at starting of a line
for multiple line comments add  **'**  (single quote) from where you want to start & add  **'**  (again single quote) at the point where you want to end the comment line.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 6):

**Single Line Comments:**

Starts with "#"

For Example:

```bash
# This whole line is a comment and will not be executed
```

**Multi Line Comments:**

Starts with "<<commentName" and Ends with "commentName"

For Example:

```bash
<<commentName 

Now this whole section is a comment,
until you specify the comment name again
to end the comment section.

commentName
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

You have to rely on '#' but to make the task easier in vi you can perform the following (press escape first):

```
:10,20 s/^/#
```

with 10 and 20 being the start and end line numbers of the lines you want to comment out

and to undo when you are complete:

```
:10,20 s/^#//
```

Answer (score 0):

Save as `shellcommenttest.sh`, make executable with `chmod +x shellcommenttest.sh`, and run with `./shellcommenttest.sh`

```
echo Comment demo, there should be no output after this line.

# option 1, also works in zsh cli
false && my comment 1

# option 2
if [[ ! 0 ]]; then
  my comment 2
  can be multiline
fi

# Pretty but don't work in zsh cli:

# option 3
# my comment 3

# option 4, heredoc
<<EOF
my comment 4
can be multiline
EOF
```