# How does : <<'END' work in bash to create a multi-line comment block?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I found a great answer for how to [comment in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/947936/1093607) (by [@sunny256](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93279/sunny256)):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> echo before comment
> : <<'END'
> bla bla
> blurfl
> END
> echo after comment
> ```
>
> The `'` and `'` around the `END` delimiter are important, otherwise things inside the block like for example `$(command)` will be parsed and executed.

This may be ugly, but it works and I'm keen to know what it means. Can anybody explain it simply? I did already find an explanation for `:` that it is no-op or true. But it does not make sense to me to call no-op or true anyway....

Comment: Yes, it's ugly. Yes, it works. But there's a much better way to comment out blocks of code in a bash script: just precede each line with a `#` character. If your editor doesn't let you do that easily (without explicitly inserting the `#` on each line, one at a time), find a better editor.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'm afraid this explanation is less "simple" and more "thorough", but here we go.

The goal of a comment is to be text that is *not* interpreted or executed as code.

Originally, the UNIX shell did not have a comment syntax *per se*. It did, however, have the null command `:` (once an actual binary program on disk, `/bin/:`), which ignores its arguments and does nothing but indicate successful execution to the calling shell. Effectively, it's a synonym for `true` that looks like punctuation instead of a word, so you could put a line like this in your script:

```
: This is a comment
```

It's not quite a traditional comment; it's still an actual command that the shell executes. But since the command doesn't *do* anything, surely it's close enough: mission accomplished! Right?

The problem is that the line is still treated as a command beyond simply being run as one. Most importantly, lexical analysis -  parameter substitution, word splitting, and such - still takes place on those destined-to-be-ignored arguments. Such processing means you run the risk of a syntax error in a "comment" crashing your whole script:

```
 : Let's see what happens next
 echo "Hello, world!"
 #=> hello.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

That problem led to the introduction of a genuine comment syntax: the now-familiar `#` (which debuted in the C shell created at BSD before being borrowed back into vanilla sh). Everything from `#` to the end of the line is completely ignored by the shell, so you can put anything you like there without worrying about syntactic validity:

```
 # Let's see what happens next
 echo "Hello, world!"
 #=> Hello, world!
```

And that's *How The Shell Got Its Comment Syntax*.

However, you were looking for a multi-line (block) comment, of the sort introduced by `/*` (and terminated by `*/`) in C or Java. Unfortunately, the shell simply does not have such a syntax. The normal way to comment out a block of consecutive lines - and the one I recommend - is simply to put a `#` in front of each one. But that is admittedly not a particularly "multi-line" approach.

Since the shell supports multi-line string-literals, you could just use `:` with such a string as an argument:

```
: 'So
this is all
a "comment"
'
```

But that has all the same problems as single-line `:`. You could also use backslashes at the end of each line to build a long command line with multiple arguments instead of one long string, but that's even more annoying than putting a `#` at the front, and more fragile since trailing whitespace breaks the line-continuation.

The solution you found uses what is called a [here-document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). The syntax `some-command <<whatever` causes the following lines of text - from the line immediately after the command, up to but not including the next line containing only the text `whatever` - to be read and fed as standard input to `some-command`.  Here's an alternative to the usual `echo`-based shell implementation of "Hello, world" which takes advantage of this feature:

```
cat <<EOF
Hello, world
EOF
```

If you replace `cat` with our old friend `:`, you'll find that it ignores not only its arguments but also its input: you can feed whatever you want to it, and it will still do nothing (and still indicate that it did that nothing successfully).

However, the contents of a here-document do undergo string processing. So just as with the single-line `:` comment, the here-document version runs the risk of syntax errors inside what is not meant to be executable code:

```
#!/bin/sh -e 
: <<EOF
(This is a backtick: `)
EOF
echo 'In modern shells, $(...) is preferred over backticks.'
#=> ./demo.sh: line 2: bad substitution: no closing "`" in `
```

The solution, as seen in the code you found, is to quote the end-of-document "sentinel" (the `EOF` or `END` or whatever) on the line introducing the here document (e.g. `<<'EOF'`). Doing this causes the entire body of the here-document to be treated as literal text - no parameter expansion or other processing occurs. Instead, the text is fed to the command unchanged, just as if it were being read from a file. So, other than a line consisting of nothing but the sentinel, the here-document can contain any characters at all:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
: <<'EOF'
(This is a backtick: `)
EOF
echo 'In modern shells, $(...) is preferred over backticks.'
#=> In modern shells, $(...) is preferred over backticks.
```

(It is worth noting that the *way* you quote the sentinel doesn't matter - you can use `<<'EOF'`, `<<E"OF"`, or even `<<EO\F`; all have the same result. This is different from the way here-documents work in some other languages, such as Perl and Ruby, where the content is treated differently depending on the way the sentinel is quoted.)

Notwithstanding any of the above, I strongly recommend that you instead just put a `#` at the front of each line you want to comment out. Any decent code editor will make that operation easy - even plain old `vi` - and the benefit is that nobody reading your code will have to spend energy figuring out what's going on with something that is, after all, intended to be documentation for their benefit.

Comment: Very thorough explanation of the downsides and side-effects. Great answer!

Comment: Also adding good practices hints. Definitely worth to read every word. Thx!

Comment: Great answer! What happens if the command is omitted before << ? As I tested, seems bash does not complain, and the $? is also 0. What happened in this case?  Thanks!

Comment: That also seems to work in bash and ksh, @bruin. Not sure it always would have worked in `sh`, or exactly when here-documents were added to the shell, so I don't know the history there. But it doesn't work in zsh, where a bare here-document is treated as if it were a `cat` command instead of a no-op.

Comment: Here documents are part of the original 7th Edition UNIX™ Bourne Shell — they apply in all Bourne shell derivatives, therefore. At that time, the shebang notation (`#!/bin/sh` etc as the first line) also did not have kernel support. The C shell would look at the first character of the script, and if it was `#` it assumed it was a C shell script (since Bourne shell didn't have `#` comments at the time); if it was a `:` (or any other character than a `#`), then it would be treated as a Bourne shell script (so the script would be run by `/bin/sh`). This goes by the wayside with shebang support.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a [Here Documen](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)t. It is a code block that lets you send a list of commands to another command or program

The string following the `<<` is the marker determining the end of the block. If you send commands to no-op, nothing happens, which is why you can use it as a comment block.

Answer (score -1):

That's [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) syntax.  It's a way of defining multi-line string literals.

As the answer at your link explains, the single quotes around the END disables interpolation, similar to the way single-quoted strings disable interpolation in regular bash strings.

Comment: In other languages, that's true, but in the shell, heredocs are _not_ string literals. They turn into an input stream; `<<EOF` works like `<filename`, not `'string goes here'`. You can use command substitution to _turn_ them into a string, just as you can with the `<filename` version, but they aren't like Perl/Ruby/Terraform heredocs where the construct is parsed as a string in the first place.