# Multiline comment in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

What is the best way to add multiline comments in the bash shell script?
Currently, I am using each line starting with #, let me know if there is another way to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Way to create multiline comments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158140/way-to-create-multiline-comments-in-bash)